# How to extract sub-string before or after nth character

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to extract the domain URL and resource identifier using REGEXTRACT.

For example in

`http://www.examaple.com/identifier`

I would like to extract the domain URL

`http://www.examaple.com`

and the resource ID

`identifier`

using the third forward slash `/` as a pivot.

One cell should read

`http://www.examaple.com`

and another cell should read.

`identifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part:

```
=left(A1 ,find("/",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"//","||"))-1)
```

Second part:

```
=mid(A1, find("/",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"//","||"))+1,len(A1))
```

Use find to find the / and manipulate accordingly, we change "//" to "||" to stop it finding that first.

Edit: Apologies I didn't see where you stated you want top use Regextract, I will leave this here as an alternative though.

Comment: That is quite bizarre because it works for me on Google sheets. What does it give you as a result?

Comment: Alternatively you can use a substitute referencing the first formula as what to find and nothing as the replace, this will give you the remainder of the string.